# Retrieving data from Excel cells with C#

Tags: c#, excel

please look at my code below, I tried to get the excel worksheet cells values with C#. However when I checked the values in the immediate window, they are not match with the real values at all. Some are null. Why? Thanks for advice.

```
string fname;
    int nRows;
    int nCols;
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Excel.Application xlApp;
        Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
        Excel.Worksheet xlWookSheet1;
        Excel.Range xlRange;

        openFileDialog1.Filter = "(*.xls)|*.xls|(*.xlsx)|*.xlsx";
        openFileDialog1.Title = "Select an excel file";
        if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            fname = openFileDialog1.FileName;
        System.IO.FileInfo fi = new System.IO.FileInfo(fname);
        string ext = fi.Extension.ToString();
        xlApp = new Excel.ApplicationClass();
        string parameter;
        if (ext == ".xls")
            parameter = "5";
        else
            parameter = "51";
        xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(fname, 0, true, parameter, "", "", true, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", false, false, 0, true, 1, 0);
        xlWookSheet1 = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
        object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;


        xlRange = xlWookSheet1.UsedRange;
        if (xlRange != null)
        {
            nRows = xlRange.Rows.Count;
            nCols = xlRange.Columns.Count;
            xlRange = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range)xlWookSheet1.Cells[nRows, nCols];
        }

        Dictionary<int, List<int>> dict = new Dictionary<int, List<int>>();
        List<string> list1 = new List<string>();
        for (int i = 1; i < nCols; i++)
        {
            string temp = (string)(xlRange.Cells[1, i] as Excel.Range).Value2; 
            // wrong values from temp
            list1.Add(temp);
        }
```

Comment: Not sure if this will help, but I always use "Range.Value". Try using "Value" instead of "Value2"

Answer (score 3):

```
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Data;


public DataTable GetDataTableFromExcel(string FilePath, string strTableName)
        {
            string XLSConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + FilePath + ";Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1'";
            //string XLSConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + FilePath + ";Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1'";
            OleDbConnection XLSCon = new OleDbConnection(XLSConnectionString);
            OleDbDataAdapter XLSDataAdp = new OleDbDataAdapter();
            XLSDataAdp.SelectCommand = new OleDbCommand();
            XLSDataAdp.SelectCommand.Connection = XLSCon;
            try
            {
                DataTable dtXLSData = new DataTable();
                XLSCon.Open();
                XLSDataAdp.SelectCommand.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [" + strTableName + "$]";
                XLSDataAdp.Fill(dtXLSData);

                return dtXLSData;

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
            finally
            {
                XLSCon.Close();
            }
        }
```

Try this... pass the file path and the worksheet name
then parse the datatable as you like in simple way or LINQ way

Answer (score 0):

I believe that culprit would be below line:

```
xlRange = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range)xlWookSheet1.Cells[nRows, nCols];
```

This will collapse your range to just one cell - you can quickly test that by checking xlRange.Rows.Count. I will suggest that you remove this line and code should work. Another trick that you may find useful is [Range.Value](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.range.value.aspx) property will return array of values if range has multiple cells.